# Writing unit tests for a JavaScript app

Tags: javascript, unit-testing

So, usually one should first learn the basic of unit test.
I have read a few times about unit test. But Im probably lacking of good knowledges.
The usual way would be to first learn the basics and then apply to your app.
Unfortunately I dont have so much time. This is of course not your problem and there is the risk for downvote here, but I take the chance.

This is about a very tiny javascript app. What Im looking for is to relate the theory of unit testing with this tiny project and understand how to structure the testing, basicallly what to test.

One javascript-file (app.js) calls a function in another file (funcs.js) to get results from a resource, in json format.
app.js will then verify if the decoded json as length > 0.
In that case it iterates among the posts in this json structure. And for each iteration app.js will call a function in funcs.js to extract data from the json for a post and at the same time build html-structure, which is returned to app.js.

At the end, app.js will fill an html element (in app.html) with the html-structure that funcs.js delivered.

So I need now to create a few unit tests. I guess the best part to test is func.js? That file contains a few functions. For example the function for opening, parsing and returning the json resuorce. Or the function for getting the fields (during iteration) for the json structure and build an html element. And then returning it.

Am I right on that? And how am I supposed to test? Can this be a good strategy:

I create a test.js file. I pick up a few functions in funcs.js (the relevant ones). I tried to call them a few times, passing both good and bad arguments (for example first an existing resource, then an empty argument resource for the function that requests json resource).

Im still a little bit unsure about how to test the parts that will return html-elements. If you could give some advice it would be great.

-----EDIT-----

Im adding some lines  of code to better understand the situation.

In funcs.js:

```
function get_resource (url, method){
    var xhReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhReq.open(method, url, false);
    xhReq.send(null);
    var json = xhReq.responseText;
    var obj = JSON.parse(json);
    return obj;
}

function set_text(value, id){
    if(value !== undefined){
        document.getElementById(id).textContent = value;
    }
}

function set_img(value, id, img_class){
    if(value !== undefined && imageExists(value)){
        var img = document.createElement("img");
        img.src = value;
        img.className = img_class;
        document.getElementById(id).appendChild(img);
    }
}
```

In app.js:

```
var json = get_resource('example.com', 'GET');

set_text(json.name, 'title');

set_img(json.src, 'main_div', 'img_class');
```

app.html:

```
<body>
    <div id="title"></div>
    <div id="main_div"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Please show some code.

Comment: Your funcs.js sounds like a reasonable candidate for a unit test, if it has no hooks to the UI. Your app.js may also be possible to unit test, depends on the nature of it though, how deeply connected it is to the UI elements. The better you can separate your view from its dynamic functionality, the better for testing purposes.

Comment: I added a few lines of code to better understand the situation.

Answer (score 1):

I think your questions about what to test in the func.js highlight the main (IMHO) benefit of unit tests. It allows you to create the contract between app.js and func.js and shows how you want to access the code. I always think of the tests as client for my code, if it's hard to test it will usually be hard for someone to use your code. By changing the code to make it easier to test you also make the code easier to use.

So now that you have added some code, I can give you a specific example. 
Your set_text is hard to test because it references a html element. You could mock that out, but if you actually passed in the element then it would be much easier to test, just use asserts instead of the console.log messages

Also things like get resource if it just returned a json and another function handled the http call. Also as you start to write the tests for app.js you get a sense of how you will use the func.js, should you just init it and its sets values that you can retrieve, etc.

Hope that helps.

```js
function set_text(value, el){
    if(value !== undefined){
        el.textContent = value;
    }
}

var value;
var el={textContent:'not set'}

set_text(value,el);

console.log(el)

value='value'

set_text(value,el)

console.log(el)
```

Comment: So you basically saying that funcs.js has not been written that good, related to unit tests?

Comment: Ideally you should write your test and code together, if you write the code first, it makes it difficult to write the tests. funcs.js might be OK, it's just if you are writing the tests as you write the code, the test drive the design of the code

Comment: Thanks. I begun by modifying the function that fetches the json data. Im now using try/catch. If it goes in try, then I return the json-object. If it goes in catch, then I return null. I wrote a test the verifies that returns null if non existing url is used. What I wonder is how to test that the resource was fetched. In the test unit I compare with the expected result. Expecting null is easy. But how to define when you expect a json result?

Comment: What library are you using to test, you could stub out the http call and then just make sure that it returns the json that your stubbed out, how did you force it into the catch block?